# why wordpress json api plugin fetch null data

Tags: json, wordpress, api, null, posts

{"status":"ok","count":1,"count_total":1,"pages":1,"posts":[{"id":null,"type":null,"slug":null,"url":null,"status":null,"title":null,"title_plain":null,"content":null,"excerpt":null,"date":null,"modified":null,"categories":null,"tags":null,"author":null,"comments":null,"attachments":null,"comment_count":null,"comment_status":null,"thumbnail":null,"custom_fields":null}],"query":{"ignore_sticky_posts":true}}

http://localhost/rest-api/api/get_posts/

i want to get data from posts using json api plugin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.